# How do I convert my .txt file to .json in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I have a text file like this,

```
Name: john 
...some random characters
Title: Dev
...some random characters
Country: Iceland
...some random characters
Name: randy
...
Title: Professor
...
Country: Greenland
...
```

I am looking for a way to convert this into json like this,

```
{
Name: john,
Title: Dev,
Country: Iceland
},
{
Name: randy,
Title: Professor,
Country: Greenland
}
```

There's always one line of extra random characters between each important line.

I am kind of new to bash and having a hard time figuring out how to do this so I was hoping if someone here could help me.

I tried this command but didn't work,

```
jq -Rs '[ split("\n")[] | select(length > 0) | split(":") | {Name: .[0], Title: .[1], Country: .[2]}]' text.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your paricular case it can be achieved with `awk`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk -F':' '{ if ($1=="Name")  {name=$2}
             if ($1=="Title") {title=$2}
             if ($1=="Country") {print "{\nName:"name",\nTitle:"title",\nCountry:"$2"\n},"}
           }' | head -c -2
echo
```

(`head` and `echo` are used here to deal with unnecessary comma at the end.)

Example:

```
$ ./txt2json.sh <data.txt
{
Name: john,
Title: Dev,
Country: Iceland
},
{
Name: randy,
Title: Professor,
Country: Greenland
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to save the output of awk to a file?

Comment: Standard way is stdout redirection: `./txt2json.sh <data.txt >output.json`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the keys "Name", "Title" and "Country" appear in order, how about a solution combining `awk` and `jq`:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {FS=": *"; OFS=":"}
    /^Name:/ {name=$2}
    /^Title:/ {title=$2}
    /^Country:/ {print(name,title,$2)}
' text.txt | jq -Rs 'split("\n")[] | select(length > 0) | split(":") | {Name: .[0], Title: .[1], Country: .[2]}'
```

Output:

```
{
  "Name": "john",
  "Title": "Dev",
  "Country": "Iceland"
}
{
  "Name": "randy",
  "Title": "Professor",
  "Country": "Greenland"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an `ed` solution that is only tested on the GNU variant but since you're on ubuntu then this should work.

Given the file named `file.txt` and it's content.

```
Name: john
xxxsome random characters
Title: Dev
xxxsome random characters
Country: Iceland
xxxsome random characters
Name: randy
xxx
Title: Professor
xxx
Country: Greenland
xxx
Name: Foo
xxxx
Title: Anyone
xxxx
Country: FarFarAway
xxxx
```

---

The script

```sh
#!/bin/sh

ed -s file.txt <<'EOF'
v/^Name:\|^Title:\|^Country:/d
,s/^\(.*[^:]*\): \(.*\)/"\1": "\2"/
g/Name\|Title/s/$/,/
,s/^/   /
g/Country/t. \
s/.*/},/g
1,$-1g/}/t. \
s/.*/{/g
0a
{
.
$s/,//
,p
Q
EOF
```

Output

```
{
   "Name": "john",
   "Title": "Dev",
   "Country": "Iceland"
},
{
   "Name": "randy",
   "Title": "Professor",
   "Country": "Greenland"
},
{
   "Name": "Foo",
   "Title": "Anyone",
   "Country": "FarFarAway"
}
```

- Change `Q` to `wq` from the `sh` script to edit the `file.txt` in-place.
- To make the argument/file not hard coded to the script, change `file.txt` to `"$1"` then you can call the script like (assuming the script name is `myscript`

```sh
./myscript file.txt
```